# SmartAssembly dependency error with changed global_packages path

Tags: nuget, smartassembly

I changed nuget offline folder (c:user\xxx.nuget\packages) to another path in network by global_packages path in environment variables in windows and visual studio detect new location in network in .net core 6 class library project, but SmartAssembly could not detect new path and try to load from old location (I test it!) and show me Dependency not found error window.
I add my network location in DependencySearchPaths tag in SmartAssembly.settijgs file but not work.

I test this problem with last version of SmartAssembly 8.1 , but this problem exist.

I added line below in .netCore6 .csproj file and SmartAssembly detect all dependencies.

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

but I must add this line to entire projects and also new projects in future. I want to solve this problem in SmartAssembly to use net network location